# Getting checkbox value and show them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show value from checkbox checked items.
Here is my js. in console getting undefined. How to solve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/bmtx4ykc/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkAll").change(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  });
  $('#submitButton').click(function() {
    var values = $("#add input[name=chkboxName]:checked").map(function() {
      row = $(this).closest("tr");
      return {
        id: $(this).val(),
        name: $(row).find("#name").text(),
        quantity: $(row).find("#quantity").text()
      }
    }).get();
    $('#result').append(values.name);
    console.log(values.name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` resembles an array of objects, use jquery `each` to display the data:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#checkAll").change(function () {
   $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
 });
    $('#submitButton').click(function(){
        var values = $("#add input[name=chkboxName]:checked").map(function()
                     {
                         row = $(this).closest("tr");
                         return { 
                             id : $(this).val(),
                             name     : $(row).find("#name").text(),
                             quantity       : $(row).find("#quantity").text()
                     }
                  }).get();
        
        // empty the results div then loop the values and append the name
        $('#result').empty();
        $(values).each(function(){ $('#result').append(this.name + '<br />');});
       
    });
});
```

```css
  table{
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="add">
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" value="All"></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkboxName" value="1"></td>
        <td id="name">Apple</td>
        <td id="quantity">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkboxName" value="2"></td>
        <td id="name">Orange</td>
        <td id="quantity">6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="submitButton">Show in table</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Rather than `.html('')`, you could just use the [`.empty()` method](https://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Answer (score 2):

It's because the [`map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is returning an array of objects.

You are getting `undefined` because you are trying to access the `name` property of the array. You need to access the `name` property of an object in the array.

For example, if the third row is selected, then `values[0]` would return the following:

```
console.log(values[0]);
// Object {id: "2", name: "Orange", quantity: "6"}

console.log(values[0].name);
// "Orange"
```

You could simply iterate over the items in the array in order to log the `name` property of each object:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4stg21x/)

```
values.forEach(function (row) {
    console.log(row.name);
});
```

---

As a side note, `id` attribute values must be unique within a document. Use classes instead.